# How to animate a ModelViusal3D object (model)?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

Hello I'm using the helix-toolkit libary to do some graphic programming and i would like to animate an object (model). Below is my code that doesn't do anything ?

I am not quite sure what's the corret parameter for the BeginAnimation method is ?

Has any one of you experience with animations ?

"Platte" is the ModelVisual3d object I would like to animate

```cs
public void Animation(ModelVisual3D modelVisual3D )
{
    Point point = new Point(0, 20000);
    Duration d = new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 40000));
    DoubleAnimation y = new DoubleAnimation(point.Y, d);

    Platte.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.YProperty, y);
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Animation(Platte);
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at their examples ?
https://github.com/helix-toolkit/helix-toolkit/tree/master/Source/Examples

Comment: Yes I have but I couldn't find anything...

Comment: But do the examples work. isn't there some example you can modify to suit your needs ?

Comment: The examaples do work ( I can show my model and i can rotate the camera etc.) but I need a code that is able to animate or rotate this model..